# Add-PnPPageImageWebPart image resolution/responsiveness #3425

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I am fetching news form external websites using an api, i am able to download the images and create news articles in sharepoint.
But the image doesnt fit properly as we hardcode height and witdth. The height and width of images are different for each news.

Do we have something like this in pnp https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/image-helper-api
that can help us ? or we can specify height and witdh as 100% ?